Lorentz-invariant phase space integral
Consider the following Lorentz invariant integral associated to a $2\to 2$ scattering:
\begin{equation*}
I = \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p_3}}{(2\pi)^3 2E_3} \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p_4}}{(2\pi)^3 2E_4} \delta^4(p_1+p_2-p_3-p_4) \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2)
\end{equation*}
where $E_i = \sqrt{m_i^2 + \mathbf{p}_i^2}$ and $t$ is a Mandelstam variable. I would like to calculate it and further understand the result. My attemp:
First of all, because the integral is Lorentz invariant it applies to any rest frame. Namely, we can choose the CM frame where $p_1 + p_2 =p_3 + p_4 = (\sqrt{s}, \mathbf{0})$. In this case,
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p_3}}{(2\pi)^3 2\sqrt{m_4^2 + \mathbf{p}_3^2}} \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p_4}}{(2\pi)^3 2\sqrt{m_4^2 + \mathbf{p}_4^2}} \delta^3\left(\mathbf{p}_3+\mathbf{p}_4\right) \delta\left(\sqrt{s}-\sqrt{m_3^2 + \mathbf{p}_3^2}-\sqrt{m_4^2 + \mathbf{p}_4^2}\right) \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2) \\
&= \int \frac{\mathbf{p}_3^2 \ d^3\mathbf{p_3}}{(2\pi)^3 2\sqrt{m_4^2 + \mathbf{p}_3^2}} \int \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3 2\sqrt{m_4^2 + \mathbf{p}_3^2}} \delta\left(\sqrt{s}-\sqrt{m_3^2 + \mathbf{p}_3^2}-\sqrt{m_4^2 + \mathbf{p}_3^2}\right) \int d\Omega \ \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2)
\end{align*}
where in the first line I have integrated in $d^3\mathbf{p}_4$ and in the second line I changed to spherical coordinates $d^3\mathbf{p}_3 = \mathbf{p}_3^2 \ d\mathbf{p}_3 \ d(\cos\theta) \ d\phi = \mathbf{p}_3^2 \ d\Omega$. The first factor can be integrated by using delta properties giving
\begin{equation*}
I = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{|\mathbf{p}^\ast|}{4\pi \sqrt{s}} \int d\Omega \ \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2)
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{p}^\ast$ is the value of $\mathbf{p}_3$ such that the argument of the delta vanishes
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{s}-\sqrt{m_3^2 + {\mathbf{p}^\ast}^2 } - \sqrt{m_4^2 + {\mathbf{p}^\ast}^2 } =0 \Rightarrow |\mathbf{p}^\ast| = \frac{\lambda^{1/2}(s, m_3^2, m_4^2)}{2\sqrt{s}}
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2xy-2yz$.
Now, does anyone know how to handle the second factor?

You should place the definition of E in a separate code block, here's no need to place it immediately after the integral.

Using $$\frac{1}{2E}=\int\! dp^0 \,\theta(p^0)\, \delta(p^2-m^2),$$ one obtains $$\begin{align}J &: =\int\! \frac{d^3p_3}{2 E_3} \frac{d^3p_4}{2E_4} \, \delta^{(4)}(p_1+p_2-p_3-p_4) \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2) \\[5pt] &=\int\! \frac{d^3p_3}{2E_3} \,d^4p_4 \, \theta(p_4^0)\,\delta(p_4^2-m_4^2) \, \delta^{(4)}(p_1+p_2-p_3-p_4) \, \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2) \\[5pt]&=\int \! \frac{d^3p_3}{2E_3}\, \theta(p_1^0+p_2^0-p_3^0)\, \delta((p_1+p_2-p_3)^2-m_4^2)\, \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2)\\[5pt]&=\int \! d^4p_3 \, \theta(p_3^0) \, \delta(p_3^2-m_3^2) \,\theta(p_1^0+p_2^0-p_3^0)\, \delta((p_1+p_2-p_3)^2-m_4^2)\, \delta(t-(p_1-p_3)^2)\\[5pt] &=\frac{\pi}{2 \,\lambda^{1/2}(s,m_1^2,m_2^2)}, \end{align}$$ provided $t$ is the kinematical region given by $$   \left|\frac{(t-m_1^2-m_3^2)s +(p_1+p_2)\cdot p_1(s+m_3^2-m_4^2)}{\lambda^{1/2}(s,m_1^2,m_2^2) \,\lambda^{1/2}(s,m_3^2,m_4^2)}       \right|\le \frac{1}{2}.$$

What did you do in the last step? How did you get rid off $t$? Thanks for the answer.

@Spectree Simply perform three integrations using the three delta-functions. The fourth integral (over an angle) gives a (trivial) factor $2\pi$. The final result is the expression shown (being independent of $t$) if the last inequality is fulfilled and $0$ otherwise. This comes from $\int\limits_{-1}^{+1} d! \cos \theta , \delta(\cos \theta-a)=\theta(1-a) \theta(a+1)$.

OK, I pressume you have changed to spherical coordinates and expanded the last delta with $\delta(f(\cos\theta))$ property.

@Spectree Yes, spherical coordinates in the COM frame. You only have to use $\delta(c x)=\delta(x)/|c|$.

This way I obtain $\delta(\cos\theta-\frac{t-m_1^2-m_3^2+2E_1E_3}{2|\mathbf{p}_1||\mathbf{p}_3|})$. So when integrating in $d(\cos\theta)$ I obtaint the same result. All in all, the final result should be the numerical value plus the constraining condition on $\cos\theta$, right?

Yes, as $-1 \le \cos \theta \le1$, this corresponds to the inequality given in the last line of my answer.
